# How to make animate.css animation loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-animations

I want to do is the `Loading header tag` should animate until progress bar reach 100%. Can anyone help me do that?

animate.css link: https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

current output: http://jsfiddle.net/GZSH6/45/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [my modified animate.css](http://howderek.com/css/animate.css) and add the `forever` class to whatever you are animating

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/GZSH6/49/**

Answer (score 44):

Animate.css have the infinite class i.e.:

```
<h1 class="animated infinite bounce">Example</h1>
```

Comment: Works like a charm without adding CSS. This class is designed for it.

Comment: Not working for me. I've tried adding `animate__animated animate__bounce animate__infinite` and it doesn't work either, docs say you need "animate__" as a prefix? I've got the CDN hooked up too

Comment: This worked for me`class="animate__animated animate__swing animate__infinite"`

Answer (score 1):

[@v4.1.1](https://animate.style/#usage) `<h1 className="animate__animated animate__heartBeat animate__infinite">❤</h1>` works fine. demo [@my-stackblitz](https://animatecss-infinite.stackblitz.io). Full code is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/animatecss-infinite?file=src/App.js)